# Why do my chrome extension script not working on web pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am making a chrome extension to show the meaning of the selected word on a web page. The script is working on the text that I write in "body" in my html file.

**But it is not working for other web pages on internet**.

Here is my dict.html file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dictionary</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dictionary.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  Crime Small Bad Smart
    <div id="tooltip" style="display:none";></div>
</body>
```

Here is dictionary.js file

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   document.ondblclick = function(evt) {
     showButton();
   }
});
function GetSelectedText () {
   var selText = "";
   if (window.getSelection) {  
      var selRange = window.getSelection ();
                selText = selRange.toString ();
        }
        else {
            if (document.selection.createRange) { // Internet Explorer
                var range = document.selection.createRange ();
                selText = range.text;
            }
        }
        return selText;
    }

    var search;
    function showButton(selector){
        search = GetSelectedText();
        var lastChar = search.substr(search.length - 1);
        if(lastChar == " ")
          search = search.slice(0,-1)

        var meaning;
        $.ajax({

        url: "http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/word.json/"+search+"/definitions?limit=200&includeRelated=true&useCanonical=false&includeTags=false&api_key=a2a73e7b926c924fad7001ca3111acd55af2ffabf50eb4ae5",
            data: ({ issession : 1, selector: selector }),
            cache: false,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            meaning = json[0].text;
            callon(meaning);
            return meaning;
            }
        });
    }
    function callon(meaning){
        $("div").attr({
         title: search     

   }).appendTo("#tooltip");

   $("#tooltip").empty().append(meaning);

   $(function() {
            $( "#tooltip" ).dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               show: {
                  effect: "explode",
                  duration: 500
               },
              hide: {
                  effect: "explode",
                   duration: 500
              }


            });
                         $( "#tooltip" ).dialog('open');

        });


          $( "#tooltip" ).dialog({

              close: function (event, ui) {
              $("#tooltip").dialog("destroy");
            }
            });
     }
```

Here is my menifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "dictionary",
  "description": "This extension defines the words",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
  {
      "matches": ["https://*/* "],
      "css": ["jqueryuid.css"],
      "js": ["dictionary.js","jqueryui.js","jquery.js"]
  }
],
 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png",
 "default_popup": "dict.html"
},
 "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/"
  ]
}
```

I have both the jquery.js and jqueryui.js file in my extension's folder.

Comment: **How** is it not working? Any errors?

Comment: on clicking the extension "Crime Small Bad Smart" are displayed. I get the meaning of the word(on a dialog box) if i double click(select) on it. But when I double click on any word of a website to get the meaning, nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your load order in the manifest is wrong. Your script loads before jQuery is ready.

It should be:

```
  "content_scripts": [
  {
      "matches": ["https://*/* "],
      "css": ["jqueryuid.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","jqueryui.js","dictionary.js"]
  }
```

To help debug such problems, get yourself acquainted with Chrome Dev Tools. Your error would generate a meaningful message in the page's console.

---

I also don't see where you add `#tooltip` to the page. I suggest making the name more unique: a lot of pages may already have an element with an ID "tooltip"

Comment: now the error is "Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (min-resolution: 144dpi), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) "

Comment: That doesn't sound like an _error_, it's a _warning_ regarding jquery-ui's CSS, not your code - if not even the webpage's own CSS.

Comment: sorry, This time nothing happens and  console is not showing any error.

Comment: Amend your `"matches"` part: `"matches": ["*://*/*"]`. Right now it has an extra space that might be significant, and doesn't match http.

Comment: yeah! i can see meaning on alert boxes now. but not on the dialog box on the screen. How can I set up tooltip to display near the word selected. I am new.

Comment: That's a very different question. As I noted in my answer, you are trying to manipulate `#tooltip` while it doesn't exist on the page. Try to solve it yourself first, and if you fail - make another question.

Comment: Please accept this answer - it would allow to mark other questions with wrong load order as duplicates.